# Combine two int arrays without duplicates using only for loops

Tags: java, arrays

This is a pretty beginner assignment, and I would love to get some help with my code.

I need to combine two integer arrays into one using for loops, and make sure I don't have duplicates. Anything I googled is pretty over complicated and uses all sorts of built in methods.

Here is my code:

```
static void SumArray(){
        int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] array2 = { 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] merged = new int[array1.length + array2.length];
        int pos = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            merged[pos] = array1[i];
            pos++;
        }
        for (int j = merged[pos]; j < array2.length; j++) {
            if (merged[pos] != array2[j]) {
                merged[pos] = array2[j];
                pos++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(merged));
```

Ultimately, it should return `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`. Instead, currently it returns `1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5`.

I would like to know why my `if` doesn't work. It should skip the 3 since it is already in there.

What am I missing?

Thanks :)

Edit:

Thanks guys, this is what I ended up doing, which still isn't good since I'm not checking for duplicates in the first loop that goes over the first array:

```java
    static void SumArray(){
        int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] array2 = { 3, 4, 5 };
        int arrSize = array1.length + array2.length;
        int[] merged = new int[arrSize];
        int pos = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            merged[pos] = array1[i];
            pos++;
        }
        for (int j = merged[pos]; j < array2.length; j++) {
            if (merged[pos-1] != array2[j]) {
                merged[pos] = array2[j];
                pos++;
                counter++;
            }
        }

        int[] newMerged = new int[arrSize - counter + 1];
        System.arraycopy(merged, 0, newMerged, 0, newMerged.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newMerged));
        }
```

I'm sure I'll find a way.

Comment: You check the wrong index: `if (merged[pos] != array2[j]) {` should be `if (merged[pos - 1] != array2[j]) {`. Notice that the code only works if `array1` and `array2` written behind each other is ordered. Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

because of the  "pos++" in the first for loop as you are using as start index of j in the second loop.
Your 3 is in the index 2 and you are comparing it to index 3, which never be equal

here is your answer:

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] array2 = { 3, 4, 5 };
int[] merged = new int[array1.length + array2.length];
    int pos = 0,i=0, j;

    Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet();

    for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if(!intSet.contains(array1[i])) {
        merged[pos] = array1[i];
        intSet.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
        pos++;

        }
    }

    for (j= 0, pos = pos-1; j < array2.length; ) {
        if(!intSet.contains(Integer.valueOf(array2[j]))) {
            merged[pos] = array2[j];
            intSet.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
            pos++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(merged));
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know why my `if` doesn't work.

Because `merged[pos]` is always 0, because you've never assigned any other value to it in your code. Array entries are initialized to zero when you create the array.

You can't just check one entry to know whether to add a value from `array2`. You have to check **all** of the entries you've written, with a nested loop within your second `for` loop. Only add a new entry if it isn't already there.

Note that you'll also need to either check ahead of time how many duplicates there are so you know that `merged` should only be 5 entries long, or you need to re-create `merged` later when you know how long it should be. Otherwise, your end result will be `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0}`, not `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is solution for Java 8 and bigger version:

```
int[] first = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] second = { 3, 4, 5 };
int[] merged = Stream.of(first, second)
            .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
            .distinct()
            .toArray();
```